# How to test that a new record in the controller has an attribute

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

I know I can use `assigns` to see if instance variables are assigned to something, but how do I test that another property has been set?

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
     @user = User.new
     @user.name = "Tom Lehrer"
  end
end

describe UsersController do
  it "assigns a user" do
    get :new
    expect(assigns(:user)).to be_a_new(User)
  end

  it "sets the new users name" do
    # ??
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just test against `assigns(:user)`:

```rb
expect(assigns(:user).name).to eq("Expected Name")
```

Answer (score 2):

assigns(:user).name.should == 'Name here'

Answer (score 0):

Isn't obvious?

```
User.any_instance.should_receive(:name).with("Tom Lehrer")
get :new
```